# How to draw with video using html-canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I was wondering how I can "draw" with an image (example shown below) using Javascript and canvas? "Draw," in the sense that the image would follow the mouse and repeatedly place itself every time the mouse changes position.

**EDIT:** Okay, so to narrow down my question. Basically, I am wondering how do I "draw" with an image using the canvas tag?  How would I "draw" with a video object?

[image]

Comment: _""Draw," in the sense that the image would follow the mouse and repeatedly place itself every time the mouse changes position."_ Continuously append new image to document , or single image follows cursor ?

Comment: Looking at the sketch above, which is what I want to achieve, I would say it's continuously creating a new image object (although it has to be of the same image) and then placing it.

Comment: When I mention the cursor, I just mean that it would be placed at the location of the cursor.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359899/background-color-on-a-specific-area-of-an-element

Comment: Ok thanks. But how would I put other elements behind the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite straight forward :

- Load an image
- Get your mouse's coords
- Draw the image at these coords
- Use CSS for positioning your elements

The main point being to not clear your canvas.

```js
canvas.onmousemove = draw;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/50/50?'+Math.random();
function draw(e){
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX-rect.left-img.width/2;
  var y = e.clientY-rect.top-img.height/2;
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width, img.height);
  }
```

```css
canvas{position: absolute; z-index:1;}
#up{z-index:2; background-color:rgba(125,0,125,.5);}
p{position: relative; background-color:rgba(0,125,125,.5); color:#ccc}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
<p id="up">There is something behind me</p>
<p id="down">There is something above me</p>
```